# How restrict attribute names in entity attribute value?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, entity-attribute-value

[This pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) allows attaching multiple attributes to one entity. Say that entity has a type which defines a set of attributes. How constraining attributes for MySQL which do not support custom constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Constraining the possible attributes will defeat the purpose of the pattern...

There are 3 ways to do it:

1. use an `enum` column for the attribute
2. add a foreign key to a table with a list of allowed attributes
3. add a insert/update trigger and do whatever validation you want in it